# index.php downloads but doesn't run in browser

Tags: php, html, apache

I have zero experience with php and I'm trying to run a simple php doc that references other php docs in the main directory. I can't get the index.php to run in a browser window, it just keeps trying to download the file instead.

Reseller server (I run many websites from this server, including a lot of wordpress sites,) Linux with the latest versions of MySQL, PHP and Apache. htaccess doc works fine.

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡ lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php include('head.php');?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('main-content.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: What happens if you hit the file directly?

Comment: @atymic It will do the same thing. Try to download the file instead of running it.

Comment: Chances are there's an issue with the server config then. Can you check if the PHP module is loaded?

Comment: I fixed the issue making a fresh new server environment for the project.